# How to can I search range of products using between

Tags: query-posts

I want to show the range of my houses as per size. Ranges will be:

1-50
50-100
100-150
150-200
200-250
+250.

**HTML code**

```
<select name="size" id="search-type" class="text<?php echo $select_wide; ?>">
    <option value=""><?php _e('Size..', TS_DOMAIN); ?>&hellip;</option>
    <option name="size" value="1">1-50 M2</option>
    <option name="size" value="5000">50-100 M2</option>
    <option name="size" value="10000">100-150 M2</option>
    <option name="size" value="15000">150-200 M2</option>
    <option name="size" value="20000">200-250 M2</option>
    <option name="size" value="999999">+250 M2</option>     
</select>
```

**PHP code**

```
// check size custom fields

if($search_get['size'])
    $meta_query_size = array(    
        'key' => '_size',
        'value' => array($search_get['size'],10000),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    );
```

Note: If I use the query below, then it works, but not for `between`.

```
// check size custom fields

if($search_get['size'])
    $meta_query_size = array(
            'key' => '_size',
            'value' => $search_get['size'],
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        );
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something wrong with your incoming variable? try without $variable. simply with already setted value and check results.

```
  'value' => array(100,10000)
```